# Как подключить к SQL базе данных в UNITY 3D

Tags: c#, sql, unity3d

стало интересно, как подключиться к базе данных SQL в Unity 3D. Я нашёл пару статей, что это необходимо делать через php, но так,как навыки в данном языке равны меньше нуля, то хотелось бы узнать, есть ли другая возможность. Спасибо)

Comment: php не тяжёлый. [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045220/unity3d-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-ms-sql/1045242#1045242)

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю, что есть какая-то разница между подключение БД к UNITY и к какому-нибудь консольному приложению:

```
string connetionString;
connetionString = @"Data Source=WIN-50GP30FGO75;Initial Catalog=Demodb;User ID=sa;Password=demol23";
using( var cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
  cnn.Open();
```

Однако, использовать БД в `UNITY` приложении- это странное решение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, просто зашёл спор, и тк у меня юнити нету, я не мог попробовать)

Comment: Не сработает) не видит либу

Comment: @Valera вы сборку подключили к проекту? Namespace добавили?

Comment: using System.Data.SqlClient; и пишет что не видит такого

Comment: разница есть. В Unity .Net кастрированный. С sqlite больше шансов, да и плагины есть готовые

Comment: @vmchar, так, как это дело заставить работать?) Мб можно просто библиотеку забросить в какую папку в проекте и от туда вытянуть? Такое может сработать?

Comment: @Valera интернеты молчат) Можно попробовать в .NET для Windows откопать dll где описан System.Data.SqlClient. Но опять же упрется в то, что если даже и заработает на WIn, то на других платформах не будет.

Comment: @vmchar ну о кросс-платформенности речи в вопросе не шло. Взятие DLL-ок по идее должно помочь, так как вроде сборки бинарно совместимы.

Comment: УХХХ) Предстоит покопаться)

Comment: @vmchar, не выходит, подключиться я смог к библиотеке, но выдает ошибку "PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform."

Comment: Окей, ккак узнать localhost у базы sql?

Answer (score 0):

### *Необходимо скопировать пару .dll файлов, которые связаны с библиотеками ассетов в Unity.*

А именно надо скопировать и вставить в редактора Unity файлы:

1. Data.dll
2. Data.SqlClient.dll
   (Можно портировать их в Unity с помощью "Управление пакетами NuGet")

---

Если не помогает, то нужно настроить смешанный режим авторизации в SQL Server, порты TCP/IP в настройках SQL Server Configuration и возможно поиграться с выбором Framework`а в Build Settings.

---

При сборке проекта необходимо будет закинуть в папку Assets файлы I18N.dll